# Kubernetes probes fail on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, kubernetes

I am running a Java webapp on Tomcat in a Docker image on a Kubernetes cluster. The service runs fine, I am trying to set up the liveness and readiness probes.

I haven't found documentation on best practices wrt Tomcat and Kubernetes specifically, but I considered a HTTP GET request following the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-a-liveness-http-request) to be appropriate like this:

```
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /
        port: 8080
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 20
      periodSeconds: 20
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 3
```

When accessing the Tomcat base URL, it returns a welcome page and code `200 -- OK`. However, the liveness probe fails, this is in the pod description:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age               From               Message
  ----     ------                 ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled              3m                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned xxxxx-service-7f8f76988-lkxdf to kube-03
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  3m                kubelet, kube-03   MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-b6tps"
  Normal   Created                1m (x3 over 3m)   kubelet, kube-03   Created container
  Normal   Started                1m (x3 over 3m)   kubelet, kube-03   Started container
  Warning  Unhealthy              42s (x7 over 3m)  kubelet, kube-03   Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.233.96.19:8080/: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Normal   Pulling                40s (x4 over 3m)  kubelet, kube-03   pulling image "xxxxx:4999/xxxxx/xxxxxservice:v1.3.0"
  Normal   Pulled                 40s (x4 over 3m)  kubelet, kube-03   Successfully pulled image "xxxxx:4999/xxxxx/xxxxxservice:v1.3.0"
  Normal   Killing                40s (x3 over 2m)  kubelet, kube-03   Killing container with id docker://xxxxx-service:Container failed liveness probe.. Container will be killed and recreated.
```

The same goes for the readiness probe when set up in the same way.
However, when I deactivate the probes, the service runs fine. I can access the Tomcat welcome page with `/` as well as the actual webapp.

My question is hence: how should I correctly set up Kubernetes liveness/readiness probes for a Tomcat webapp? Why does the simple `HTTP GET` approach fail?

Related issues seem to be due to startup times longer than what is set in the `initialDelaySeconds` parameter (e.g. [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/51096)), just like the error message indicates. However, Tomcat and the webapp really are accessible after a few seconds in this case, so the startup time is not the issue here.

Here are the deployment specs:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: xxxxx-service
  namespace: xxxxx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: xxxxx-service
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regsecret
      containers:
      - image: xxxxxservice:v1.3.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: xxxxx-service
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "0.2"
            memory: 4Gi
```

Comment: Can you tell the `ContainerPort` value of your Tomcat application?

Comment: @AntonKostenko I've added the full deployment specs. Port is 8080 (Tomcat default).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. After a while investigating, I found out that tomcat server in my application took about 35 seconds to start. Thus, I changed initialDelaySeconds to greater than 35 seconds. I also increased time-out seconds to 10 and periods_second to 10 seconds. Kubernetes probe then worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks good and should work, but in the events I see:

```
Get http://10.233.96.19:8080/: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

That means `kubelet` was connected to your pod, but the request was cancelled because timeout exceeded while it was waiting for headers.

So, I think the problem is in your application, it can be:

1. Incorrect default routing rules. By default, `kubelet` is sending a request without any headers (include `Host`), so maybe application just does not know what to do with that request. Try to set a `Host` header like that:

   ```
   livenessProbe:
     httpGet:
       httpHeaders:
         Host: <desired.host.of.application.com>
   ```
2. At the start, the application can work a bit slow. In that case, 3 seconds of timeout can be not enough. You can try to increase the `timeoutSeconds` value.

Comment: Thanks!
I think option 2 can be ruled out; I increased the `timeoutSeconds` to 30 and the error persisted. The service usually responds within <1s so I tend to option 1, which also corresponds to an issue I've had with a non-working Ingress.
However, the error message remains the same (except the IP changes) when adding the host header.
BTW, it needs to be in the format `name`: ...; `value`: ....
I am a bit unclear about what the 'desired host' should be.

Comment: 'desired host' is your external hostname of the service, which you are using on Ingress, for example. In short - that is what you print as an address in your browser to access your service.